# Simplify doesn't simplify some simple inequalities

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I have an pair of inequalities joined by `Or` that I can't get `Simplify` or `FullSimplify` to simplify:

```
Simplify[x > y || x > y + z, Assumptions -> {x > 0, y > 0, z > 0}]
(* x > y || x > y + z *)
```

when I expected

```
(* x > y *)
```

since `x > y + z` seems to imply `x > y` when `z > 0`.

Any ideas on how to get this result? (unless I'm making a boneheaded logical error myself :)

Comment: Perhaps, you should advise Wolfram, Inc of this problem.

Comment: I hadn't considered it an actual bug, but that may be worth a shot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Reduce` instead.

```
Reduce[(x > y || x > y + z) && x > 0 && y > 0 && z > 0] 
(* y > 0 && x > y && z > 0 *)
```

Edit: As suggested by [Julien Kluge](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/34129/julien-kluge), using `Refine` as well produces a cleaner answer.

```
Refine[Reduce[(x > y || x > y + z), (x | y | z) ∈ Reals] , x > 0 && y > 0 && z > 0]
(* y < x *)
```

Comment: This could be further shortened if we use Refine with the same Assumptions as above.

Comment: No no. Reduce is nessecary. Refine would only be useful to shorten your output to the expected `x>y`.

Comment: Both of these functions are unfamiliar to me, so thanks!  Unfortunately I won't know what the variables are in my application, so `Reduce` isn't so great for that application.